# Selecting a collapsible menu item's link but not its descendants

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a function where I toggle the background image (the plus and minus icons).

When I expand the sublist and click the link it also toggles its child item's icon, but it shouldn't. Which results in adding the minus icon.

```
$('.expandor a:first-child').click(function (e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
    $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('expandor dexpandor');
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0ctv1su3/)
[image]
the minus icons should be there when clicked only Windows 8 should toggle the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('.expandor a:first-child').click
```

to this:

```
$('.expandor > a:first-child').click
//           ^ -------------------------- explicit child selector
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0ctv1su3/2/)**

Also, I suspect that the `:first-child` pseudo-selector is unnecessary here.

Comment: perfect, Thanks!!! Can you explain why the first one didn't work as it is defined as child.

Comment: No, it isn't. It's a descendant selector, which searches all subordinate elements. (Your grandchildren are not your children.)

Comment: but it says firs-child that is a link,

Comment: True, but that's a first child *anywhere* inside the list item having class `expandor`. The `first-child` pseudo-selector applies to the anchor, not parent element. Your sub-items' links are also first children within their context.